# Is the Microsoft walkthrough "Inheriting from a Windows Forms Control" a valid procedure?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, inheritance, controls

**Updated**

I'm somewhat new to Visual Studio and C#. I've come across a number of S.O posts where the answer refers to deriving (through inheritance) from a Microsoft base class and extending it. I've been meaning to figure out how to add custom properties to a base WinForms control and manage it in Visual Studio.

I stumbled across a [Microsoft procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-inheriting-from-a-windows-forms-control-with-visual-csharp) for doing so. After seeing the response to summarizing this procedure, I'm changing the question and deleting the summary (my original answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments by Ron Beyer on the Microsoft procedure follow.

Bottom line, just build the derived class from scratch. The result will be the same

> I really recommend against using a new "User Control" object and then changing the base class in the code-behind. This breaks the designer (you have to hand-edit the AutoScale property) and really there is no reason for the designer. Just start a new class file and derive the appropriate control, no need to do all the steps above. RonBeyer
>
> @RonBeyer: For example, if I create a new class file (instead of a new project), how would I reuse the custom control in another project? If I don't use the procedure, how and where do I implement the Dispose method currently provided by the Designer.cs file? Do I need to re-implement the guts of the InitializeComponent method provided by the Designer.cs file, or will the InitializeComponent method in my standalone project take care of it? Is it really just as simple as creating a new class file? NovaSysEng
>
> Yes, it is that simple. You don't need the Dispose method, the base class has it, unless you are using additional unmanaged resources, then you implement it normally (and call base.Dispose). You don't need the IntializeComponent call at all, you can add your own initialization code to the constructor if needed. Literally public class MyButton : Button { } is a perfectly valid derived control. RonBeyer

Comment: I really recommend *against* using a new "User Control" object and then changing the base class in the code-behind. This breaks the designer (you have to hand-edit the `AutoScale` property) and really there is no reason for the designer. Just start a new class file and derive the appropriate control, no need to do all the steps above.

Comment: Maybe post your alternative answer? Use the `TreeView` control as an example :-)

Comment: @RonBeyer: For example, if I create a new class file (instead of a new project), how would I reuse the custom control in another project? If I don't use the procedure, how and where do I implement the `Dispose` method currently provided by the `Designer.cs` file? Do I need to re-implement the guts of the `InitializeComponent` method  provided by the `Designer.cs` file, or will the `InitializeComponent` method in my standalone project take care of it? Is it really just as simple as creating a new class file?

Comment: Yes, it is that simple. You don't need the `Dispose` method, the base class has it, unless you are using additional unmanaged resources, then you implement it normally (and call `base.Dispose`). You don't need the `IntializeComponent` call at all, you can add your own initialization code to the constructor if needed. Literally `public class MyButton : Button { }` is a perfectly valid derived control.

Comment: @RonBeyer: I changed the Q and the A. Thanks for your guidance

Comment: `Comments on the Microsoft procedure are below.`  There is nothing "below".

Comment: @LarsTech: Modified the answer to reference the "comments section", i.e., this section where comments are

Comment: Then I would copy the comments and put them in your answer, attributed, of course.

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter. I got whanged -6 for the original Q&A - they're not coming back to rate the new Q&A.

Comment: Your answer will attract downvotes in the future and probably be flagged as "not an answer".

Comment: I took's Ron's advice and built my derived classes from scratch, FYI, for VS users, see also [Why does VS2017 keep losing my derived controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50472308/why-does-vs2017-keep-losing-my-derived-controls)