# Why does VS2017 keep losing my derived controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, inheritance, controls

In my app `namespace = DRT`, I'm creating control classes (e.g., button, textbox) that derive fron their corresponding Windows control classes, e.g.,

```
internal abstract class DRT_Button_Abstract : Button
{
    ....
}

internal class DRT_Button_CancelSearch : DRT_Button_Abstract
{
    ....
}

internal class DRT_Button_StartSearch : DRT_Button_Abstract
{
    ....
}
```

All together I currently have 13 derived classes that derive either from one of my abstracts or from a Windows control class. After a successful build, I see my control classes (e.g., `DRT_Button_CancelSearch` and `DRT_Button_StartSearch`) on the Toolbox and I successfully drop them onto my main form. All is fine for a while, but ultimately, I'll go to open the main form.cs [Design] (i.e., the UI designer) and it will show the error `The variable '{control property name}' is either undeclared or was never assigned.` for some combination of my controls.

When I examine the main form Designer.cs file, the expected code for all the controls is present EXCEPT for the expected `new` statement. They are not present in the main form Designer.cs file. For example, I expect to see `this.drt_Button_CancelSearch = new DRT.DRT_Button_CancelSearch();` but its missing

I've tried ignoring the error, proceeding to the UI designer windows to re-apply the lost controls, but the problem just repeats with the newly applied control

What the heck is going on? Is there a way to recover from this situation?

Comment: Do all of your derived controls have default constructors? Have you tried marking them `public` instead of `internal`?

Comment: @RonBeyer: For default constructors: If I understand you correctly, I think I was missing some. For each of my abstract classes and for each of my derived classes, I added `: base()` to the class's constructor definition , e.g., `public DRT_Button_Abstract(): base()` and `public DRT_Button_CancelSearch() : base()`. Correct? Will also set all to `public` and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a problem of the Designer not being able to clear/reload its cache. There is not much you can do. In the past I:

- closed and reopened all designers that have user controls
- put all the controls in a separate project (in the same solution)
- put all the controls in a separate solution/Visual Studio instance and set a proper reference to the controls' dll (or even nuget package)

With the first two options I have had varying success. Reopening the designer is not very convenient and doesn't work.

That last option is the best but also the most annoying because every adjustment requires a rebuild of the project and update of the reference/package.

Also make sure that all controls that you create have public default constructors and function well when this constructor is used.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because both Erno and Ron called out the public constructors, but Ron's `Do all of your derived controls have default constructors` also forced me to find how some of my classes were missing `: base()`. In any case, ensuring all of my classes (including abstract) have `: base()` and marking them public seems to have fixed my problem